# Facebook messenger api - pass conversation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have passed a conversation from a primary application to a secondary application, I used the call https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/pass_thread_control with the following data:

```
{"recipient": {"id": "xxxxxxxx"},
"target_app_id": xxxxxx,
"metadata": "test to pass to secondary receiver app",
"pass_thread_control": {
    "new_owner_app_id": "xxxxx",
    "metadata": "metadata to test"
  }
 }
```

it has returned true, that is, the secondary application has control.

The problem I have is to return the conversation to the primary application, I am using the call https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/take_thread_control

```
{
"recipient": {
"id": "xxxxxxxx"
},
"metadata": "additional content that the caller wants to set"
}
```

and returns:

```
    "error": {
        "message": "(# 10) Only Main Receiver can call this API",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 10,
        "error_subcode": 2018169,
        "fbtrace_id": "DnBvWqt / 0bd"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

What are the calls I must make consecutively?

How can I know which application has the conversation?

**Another thing that I have seen is that I have tried to make this call:**
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/secondary_receivers

and return this message:

```
"error": {
      "message": "(# 10) Only Main Receiver can call this API",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 10,
      "error_subcode": 2018169,
      "fbtrace_id": "Gt1WsVx9W22"
   }
```

Do I need some permission?

Answer (score 0):

take_thread_control and secondary_receivers can only be called by the Primary Receiver app. If you want the Secondary Receiver to pass thread control back to the Primary, you need to call pass_thread_control from the Secondary.

take_thread_control is specifically reserved for the Primary, which pass_thread_control is for primary and secondary.